# Implementing a DFS for Linux Kernel Processes using list_for_each

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to implement a DFS to print out all the processes in the linux Kernel. The list_for_each function caught my interest as follows:

```
list_for_each(list, &init_task->chidlren){
    task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
}
```

Is it possible to do a DFS using the list_for_each function? Since list_for_each only prints out the first level of children it doesn't seem possible to go to the deepest level of a single children.

Comment: How about wrapping it in a function, and then using recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just going to assume you got that code from an operating system book.  I really don't like how they trick you into thinking that list_for_each(list, &init_task->chidlren) is the correct statement you need to use.  Oliver is correct about recursion though.

You can do something similar to the following to accomplish a DFS.

```
void some_function(struct task_struct *task) {

struct list_head *list;
struct task_struct *another_task;

printk("Print out the task info here");

list_for_each(list, &task->children) {
    another_task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
    some_function(another_task);
 }
}
```

Since this is for a linux kernel module, you will also need the following.

```
int simple_init(void){

printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module By Stratos\n");

some_function(&init_task);

return 0;
}
```

&init_task is used in the code you need, just not where they put it.